# What is word for "small but powerful"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word or idiom that describes something that is small but powerful. For example, a tiny computer that is capable of doing the same work as a larger computer.

Comment: ["Pint-sized powerhouse"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PintsizedPowerhouse)? (warning: TVTropes)

Comment: In some contexts "pocket rocket"

Comment: Extremely condensed.

Comment: small but mighty

Comment: When it's about people you can use "pocket rocket".

Answer (score 1):

*Concentrated* and its synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

***best things come in small packages, good things come in small packages***

[**From TFD**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/best+things+come+in+small+packages%2C+good+things+come+in+small+packages):

> **best things come in small packages, good things come in small packages**
>
> Prov. Small packages often contain valuable things.  (Sometimes said
> of petite or short people.)
>
> Jill: I'm upset at George. He only gave me this tiny box for my
> birthday. Jane: Don't get upset till you know what's in it. Good
> things do come in small packages.
>
> Child: I hate being so short. Grandmother: You shouldn't. The best
> things come in small packages.

From [**dictionary.cambridge.org**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/good-things-come-in-small-packages):

> **good things come in small packages**
>
> *saying* ​
>
> said to emphasize that
> something does not need to be big in order to be good

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest:

> atomic

defined as meaning

> related to atoms

which as we all know are very small but immensely powerful.

Answer (score -3):

One option might be ***scaled down***

> reduce proportionally; "The model is scaled down" <sub><sup>[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scale+down)</sup></sub>

Comment: Jim, the issue with this I would say, is it doesn't include the concept of power or energy, merely the diminutive size.